# How often i should re-build and re-submit xml sitemap for news website?

Tags: cron, xml-sitemap

I have an website that get news from RSS Feeds. I build every day 2-3k articles and now i have almost 160k links.

So, how often i should re-submit the xml sitemap; (currently i do this job every hour)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your server configuration you can setup your site to run cron more often.

You can also use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, To write a rule for resubmitting site map  which can be trigger after certain time or on new content published.

It is also important to mention that search engines takes time to index - no matter whether through external links, internal links or sitemaps.

So don't think submitting site map more often will help.